# Bash exit status not caught despite set -e and/or trap being active

Tags: bash

Can someone explain the bash/set -e behaviour on the code snippet below ?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Comment if you want to test the trap only
set -e -o pipefail -u -E

# Comment if you want to test the set -e only
trap "echo ERROR CAUGHT; exit 12" ERR

function reproduce() {
    # Trigger arithmetic error on purpose
    a=$((1109962735 - hello=12272 + 1))
}

reproduce

# The script is expected to trigger the trap and/or activate the set -e. In both cases it should stop and exit here on error.

status_code=$?
echo "STATUS ${status_code}"
if [[ "${status_code}" != "0" ]];then
    echo "FIXME: why was status code not caught by set -e ?"
    echo "Executing false to prove set -e is still active"
    false
    # If the following is not executed then it proves -e is still active
    echo "set -e not active !!!!!"
    exit 2
fi
```

Here is what is obtained when executing it:

```
$ bash reproduce.sh
reproduce.sh: line 8: 1109962735 - hello=12272 + 1: attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "=12272 + 1")
STATUS 1
FIXME: why was status code it not caught by set -e ?
Executing false to prove set -e is still active
ERROR CAUGHT
```

Checking the exit code

```
$ echo $?
1
```

Bash version

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Reproduced as well with

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Additional notes, related to comments (thanks to all suggestions anyway):

- Commenting trap does not change the weird behaviour observed
- Removing set -e to only keep the trap does trigger the trap either

Comment: I would not combine `set -e` with `trap`. `trap` is invoked on error and "echo ERROR CAUGHT" is invoked. I've the impression that `trap` has higher precedence than `set -e`. Also according to Bash FAQ I think  `set -e` is discouraged, please check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105.

Comment: commenting trap does not change anything

Comment: I'd simply use the `trap` mechanism instead, e.g. `trap "exit 2" ERR`.  Also for me your script prints "STATUS 0" only. The ERR trap is not inherited by shell functions it seems, does this help: `set -o errtrace`? Otherwise see my link above on why you should avoid `set -e` in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify it; minimum amount of code required for
reproducing the issue you're dealing with is

```
set -e
: $((+)) # arithmetic expansion error
echo survived
```

According to the standard, this should never print `survived`, [it says a POSIX shell running non-interactively shall immediately exit upon an expansion error](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_01). But seemingly Bash doesn't think so. Although this difference isn't explicitly documented in the man page, in [description of POSIX mode](http://tiswww.case.edu/~chet/bash/POSIX) it says

> 27. Non-interactive shells exit if a syntax error in an arithmetic
>       expansion results in an invalid expression.

We can say this means in its default operating mode, a non-interactive Bash session doesn't exit upon such error, but as you realized, it doesn't trigger errexit mechanism, or ERR trap either. Instead, it assigns a non-zero value to `$?` an moves on.

To overcome this and get the expected behavior, you should  define `reproduce` as follows

```
function reproduce() (
    # Trigger arithmetic error on purpose
    a=$((1109962735 - hello=12272 + 1))
)
```

This way the expansion error will take place in a subshell and cause it to exit with a non-zero status, thus, errexit and trap will be able to catch it.

---

Upon dash-o's request, here is a version that sets `a` for the current execution environment when the expression is valid

```
function reproduce() {
    if : $((expression)); then
        a=$((expression))
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On surface, it looks as if bash will not trigger the trap on various SYNTAX errors. Only when it a command (external, built-in) is executed (and return non-zero), the ERR trap will be trigered.

From the man page:

> If a sigspec is ERR, the command arg is executed whenever a pipeline
>   (which may consist of a single simple command), a list,  or a compound
>   command returns a non-zero exit status, subject to the following
>   conditions ...

The ERR trap  only applies to **PIPELINE**. If bash identifies a syntax error, it aborts before executing the pipeline, therefore NO trap. Even though he documentation for '-e' specify the same condition (`if a pipeline ... exit with non-zero status`), the observed behavior is different.

If you try other expansions - e.g. command expansion- trap is triggered, as there is pipeline execution:

- a=$(bad-commands)
- a=$([)

If use try various syntax errors in arithmetic expansion, trap not triggered - there was no pipeline.

- a=$((2+))
- a=$((2 @))

Also, other bash Syntax error do not trigger the trap: `()`, `[[ ]]`.

I could not find a solution that does not require extensive changes to the source script.  May be file a bug/feature request with the bash team ?

Comment: Fun fact: executing it in a subshell `( a=$((1109962735 - hello=12272 + 1)) )` or `( reproduce )` executes the trap.

Comment: Unfortunately, when the expression is valid, `a` will not be set.